# import gspread returns an error in Python

Tags: python, google-oauth

I am trying to import gspread module, but i am getting an error:

[image]

I am not sure how to handle it. I looked at line 627 in parse.py and it makes no sense to me as frozenset value is being used as an argument in bytes() function thus it would produce a IList[Byte]. I am not sure what is wrong. Here's an excerpt from parse.py:

```
_ALWAYS_SAFE = frozenset(b'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                     b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                     b'0123456789'
                     b'_.-')
_ALWAYS_SAFE_BYTES = bytes(_ALWAYS_SAFE)
```

Comment: `gspread` is a Python 3 module, but you seem to be using Python 2.7. I don't know about IronPython, but could that be the problem?

Comment: very possible i am actually trying to run it on IronPython. I had no idea it was a Python 3 module. Is there a similar module that i can use on IronPython?